# View will show all list updated form every time changes made

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I'm new with lotus notes. Basically, I have a form. I want to create a situation where when I edit the form, that form will not be overwritten but it will automatically create a new form with an updated form. But when I open the new updated form, we can see all list of history from the old form. I can't think of any way to create it. Any suggestion would help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: you need to know the difference between FORM and DOCUMENT.

The FORM is the design element in designer that you create and that is used to create and modify DOCUMENTS.

A DOCUMENT is a set of item - value pairs stored in the database. The items are based on the FORM it is created with.

If I understand you correctly, you want to create a new DOCUMENT on every save but keep the old DOCUMENT at the same time. There is a function called "Version Tracking" that allows this.

Read [this documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_ABOUT_TRACKING_VERSIONS_OF_A_DOCUMENT.html) about how to use versioning. Here is a short version:

1. Open the form.
2. Choose Design - Form Properties.
3. On the Form Info tab, select None or one of the following versioning methods:

   - New versions become responses
   - Prior versions become responses
   - New versions become siblings

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Help me so much. Thank you for your answer! :) I have a question, what if I have DOCUMENT inside subform? Because to change version tracking only on Form right?

Comment: A subform cannot stand alone. it needs to be put into a form. So: if it is in a form with version management, then it will be versioned as the fields directly in the form.

Comment: Yes, I have a computed subform inside my form page. So I just do version tracking inside the form? Also, how can I see whether the list is shown in the view? Because after I edit, I did not see the old edit document listed in notes view.

Comment: In the view, first tab, check "show Response..." see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_10.0.1/basic/H_ABOUT_INDENTING_RESPONSE_DOCUMENTS.html

Comment: Okay, I have done that and successful with it. But it not indent. For example, I have no. the list and 9.2 is edited but it not indenting. It's just the same line. 
9.1
9.2
9.2.1

Should it be indented? Thanks!